# Broken image is displaying for the attribute value not selected

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have created a attribute `newsale` with two value `New` and `sale` with `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` as `dropdown` and added it to a attribute set. And then I have added images into the media with same name as the added value (new.png, sale.png)

My code at frontend to call the attribute in product category page is:

```
<div class="product-badge"> 
    <span> 
         <?php
           $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
           ->getAttribute('newsale')->getFrontend()
           ->getValue($_product));
            foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" ?>
                  <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/wysiwyg/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
             </a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

My problem here is even when I didn't select any value for this attribute at admin panel, a broken image is getting displayed.

Help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<div class="product-badge"> 
    <span> 
         <?php
           $Feature = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
           ->getAttribute('newsale')->getFrontend()
           ->getValue($_product));
            foreach($Feature as $key => $value): ?>
            <?php if($value == 'New' || $value =='sale') {?>
              <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" ?>
                  <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/wysiwyg/".trim($value).".png'/>"; ?>
             </a>
             <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But only sale is displayed. New is not getting displayed when selected. kindly help

Comment: check the value of new For exp : It's New Or new may be it's case sensitive